# Why is the styling not working

Tags: html, css

How do I get this form to get formatted like the css. I created the form class called database and then named the classes in the form database as well, but no changes took place. Does adding css to a form that uses js, make a difference in the way it is styled?

```
<style type="text/css">
        .database-label{
            width:150px !important;
        }
        .database-label-left{
            width:150px !important;
        }
        .database-line{
            padding-top:1px;
            padding-bottom:1px;
        }
        .database-label-right{
            width:150px !important;
        }
        .database-all{
            width:690px;
            background:transparent;
            color:#555555 !important;
            font-family:'Lucida Grande';
            font-size:14px;
        }
        .database-radio-item label, .database-checkbox-item label, .database-grading-label, .database-header{
            color:#555555;
        }


    .database-label-top
    {
    display:none !important;
    }
    .database-textbox
    {
    width: 500px !important;
    height:40px !important;
    }
    .database-save-button
    {
    width: 500px !important;
    height:40px !important;
    position:relative !important;
    left:-151px !important;
    }
    .database-all input,select {
    border: 1px solid #b7bbbd;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 140px;
    }
    .database-dropdown
    {
    width: 500px !important;
    height:40px !important;
    }

    </style>
```

---

```
<form id="database" name="database" class="database">
            <label>School</label>
            <select id="schoolList" name="schoolList" onchange="schoolChange()">
                <option value="null">Select a School</option>
            </select>

            <br />

            <label>Edit/Add a New Merchant</label><br />

            <span id="categoryNum">0</span>
            <select id="merchantCategoryList" name="merchantCategoryList" onchange="merchantCategoryChange()">
                <option value=null>New Category</option>
            </select>
            <span id="newCategory">
                <input id="newCategoryName" type="text" placeholder="Enter the name of the New Category." size="45" />
            </span>

            <br />

            <span id="merchantNum">0</span>
            <select id="merchantList" name="merchantList" onchange="merchantChange()">
                <option value="null">New Merchant</option>
            </select>
            <span id="newMerchant">
                <input id="newMerchantName" type="text" placeholder="Enter the name of the New Merchant." size="45" />
            </span>

            <br />

            <div id="merchantInfo">
                <label>Phone Number:</label>
                <input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" size="45" />
                <br />
                <label>Address:</label>
                <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Address" size="45" />
                <br />
                <label>City:</label>
                <input id="city" type="text" placeholder="City" size="45" />
                <br />
                <label>State:</label>
                <input id="state" type="text" placeholder="State" size="45" />
                <br />
                <label>Zip:</label>
                <input id="zip" type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" size="45" />
                <br />
                <label>Hours:</label>
                <input id="hours" type="text" placeholder="Hours" size="45" />
                <br />
            </div>

            <input id="Save" type="button" value="Save" onclick="save();" />
        </form>
```

Comment: Your class selection on your CSS is invalid.

Comment: I don't see any classes in HTML from css

Comment: I'd say its probably worth reading a css tutorial before getting stuck in. http://www.w3schools.com/css/DEFAULT.asp

Comment: there are a lot class names in your CSS which isn't available in HTML.

Comment: You haven't added the relevant class names in individual divs as well. Just by giving the form class as database doesn't add the css to child elements

Answer (score 1):

You haven't assigned any classes to the elements, other than the form itself.
So you can target the elements within that form, by:

```
form.database label{}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

By your form class name you have to write your css selection like this for styling element :

```
.database > label { /*for styling label }
.database > span{ /*for styling span}
.database > input{ /*for styling all input type}
.database > input[type="text"]{ /*for styling input with type text}
.database > input[type="button"]{ /*for styling input with type button}
```

Thats all from me. Good luck

Comment: uhm, the `a > b` selector means that only the elements of b within the parent a will be selected. Inner childs wouldn't be selected. In the OP's example, the elements within `div#merchantInfo` won't be selected. Just use space to select all elements within an element.

Comment: Yep, correct. For learning purpose for the questioner. Anyway do you available for collaboration on project ?

Comment: What are you asking me?

Answer (score 0):

Add classes to elements e.g. for save button use class=".database-save-button"
Else declare css classes like

```
#Save
    {
    width: 500px !important;
    height:40px !important;
    position:relative !important;
    left:-151px !important;
    }
```